# Segmentation Fault while updating repositories

Tags: apt, gnome, updates, ubuntu-gnome, segmentation-fault

When I run

```
sudo apt update
```

I get a segmentation fault with this error:

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 
 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; 
 then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

How can I fix this?

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

this is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160720)]/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
```

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get update`had the same result of above

Comment: Have you changed any `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?

Comment: @MarkYisri, not recently, I'll post my sources.list .

Comment: The ironic thing is that I would have suggested doing `apt-get update` to fix the problem, but the problem is `apt-get update`.

Comment: Well recursion is not always a bad idea, but I don't think it will works!

Comment: Nothing strange about /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: How long has this been happening?

Comment: Since last update&upgrade, i've also deleted the grive tools' repo because it wasn't working (it's not updated yet for xenial).

Comment: So you upgraded from 15.10?

Comment: No, I downloaded the ISO of 16 from the official site

Comment: And did a reinstall?

Comment: No, I used to format the HDD by gparted and then install the os so it was like to have a clean installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final resolution was to remove the whole system and install back.
I even tried a reconfiguration of `apt` using `dpkg` but it didn't work.